# CS1503 Argument1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'string[*,*]'

Tags: c#, winforms

Beginner here. The parameters of the method GetFullName() 'brnd' and 'nm' seems to be the culprit of the error -

> "CS1503 Argument1 (and Argument2): cannot convert from 'string' to
> 'string[*,*]'"

Can someone explain the problem and how to fix it? Thank you so much!

```
                if (iteminfo[row, 0] == serialcheck)
                {
                    brnd = iteminfo[row, 1];
                    nm = iteminfo[row, 2];

                    info = GetFullName(brnd,nm);
                    
                    MessageBox.Show(info);

                    return;
                }

                

    public string GetFullName(string[,] brandp, string[,] namep )
    {
        fullname = brandp + " - " + namep;
        return fullname;
    }
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error on? What is type of `info`? What is type of `iteminfo`? Also `brandp + " - " + namep` will result in "System.String[,] - System.String[,]" for non-null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `GetFullName` is clearly intended to operate on `string` values, but you have declared the parameters as two-dimensional array of `string` type, and passing `string` values as arguments -

```
info = GetFullName(brnd,nm);
```

That's the source of error.

Modify the method signature as -

```
public string GetFullName(string brandp, string namep )
{
    var fullname = brandp + " - " + namep;
    return fullname;
}
```